# How can I programmatically show the select device dialog?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I am using the Cast Companion Library and most of it is working well however I have not been able to figure out how to show the device chooser programmatically.

Basically when a user chooses a video on my app I would like to show the chooser if they haven't yet connected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the MediaRouteButton and it's accessible:

```
mediaRouteButton.performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to "Developing a custom UI with the MediaRouter API’s and MediaRouter.Callback" but I didn't find any example how to do it .

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you do not do that. I don't know what you are planning to do in your app so I can't say much but don't do something custom in terms of user interaction/flow that is different from other apps and the apps offered by the framework; people will not expect that.

On the technical side, if you want to open the standard dialog, I am not aware of any trick but I haven't looked at the MediaRouter code in v7 support library for that; since that is open source, you are welcome to look in there and see if there is any simple way to do that. If you want to design your custom one, you should be able to do that; the CastCompanionLibrary provides a sample of the Callback dialog and the one for chooser follows a similar pattern.

As a side note, you mentioned you want to open the chooser when user selects a movie. So how can they select to play locally? Are you planning to add additional selection to that dialog for local playback?

Comment: I'm trying to do this on two apps. On one app I was going to ask the user if they would like to show this on the device or chromecast and have a "don't ask again" checkbox. On the other app there is really not much point on playing the content locally as it is really only meant to be played on the chromecast. The suggestion to show the dialog when a user forgot to select a device actually came from users who often forget to do so.

Comment: to keep things uniform across apps, could you instead popup a dialog (or even a toast) if they click on the play and no device is yet selected?

Comment: Yeah, toast is what I am doing now. I might endup making my own dialog and adding "this device" to the top of the list kind of like I think netflix has.

Comment: I thought "local playback" was not even relevant for that app, so why do you want to add "this device" as an option? Our UX guidelines recommends not to add that as an option.